# Why grep is taking so much time?

Tags: unix, grep, tcl

I am using grep to count the number of occurrences of string "^mj" in a file graph.tcl.
The command which i have written is quite easy and you can easily understand.

> grep "^mj " mjwork/run/graph.tcl | wc -l

It outputs `46625` but after `~45 min`. Can you guys suggest a better approach which could reduce the time?

Comment: It is actually taking ~45 mins. I planned up to cut up the first word and then grep and count. It just works and ends up in sec. :-)

Comment: I beg your pardon? `grep` is a streaming program, so it should have no problem at all in chewing its way through lots of data quickly. The only reason for it to have a problem would be if there were some very long lines, but 10MB just isn't very big. Something _important_ is going on here that is missing from the description. It's possible that it's even happening in a different process or on a different machine (e.g., if the data is coming over the network).

Comment: try doing `cat mjwork/run/graph.tcl` and see how long that takes. The grep command should take approximately the same amount of time (actually, it should be a little quicker, as it doesn't have to print anything to the screen).

Comment: How big is the input file? Is it NFS mounted or over any other network transport? What is the record size of your file (what do the contents look like?) Can you take a small section of the file and benchmark `grep` (log a time stamp before and after ) in a script? Try making a RAM disk on your OS and copy the data into it and see if it runs faster. Run a performance monitoring tool and see what's taking the most time. You could break it down by function if you had OS/grep source code. You can also try strace (not sure Windows equivalent) etc...  to try to find bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

The following line might make it faster:

```
$ awk '/^mj/{c++}END{print c}' file
```

This will process the file only a single time and it will only print the total amount of matches. This is in contrast to your initial case where you ask grep to print everything into a buffer and process that again with `wc`.

In the end, you could also just do:

```
$ grep -c '^mj' file
```

which just returns the total matches. This is probably even faster than the awk version. Awk will, by default, attempt a field splitting, this action is not needed with the above grep.

There are many reasons why your process could be slow, heavy load on the disk, a slow nfs if you use it, extremely long lines to parse, ... without more information on the input file and the system you are running this on, it is hard to say why it is so slow.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something up with your machine. Have you enough swap space etc? What does `df -h` show? As a test, try `egrep` or `fgrep` as alternatives to grep.

Comment: I am using a 2 cpu machine. It is actually taking ~45 mins. I planned up to cut up the first word and then grep and count. It just works and ends up in sec. :-)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying you no longer have a problem?

Comment: I did :- cat mjwork/run/graph.tcl | cut -d " " -f 1 | grep mj | wc -l

Comment: @crazy_prog this is even slower, first you read the file with cat, then you read it again complete through a buffered pipe, process it with cut, read it again completely through a second buffered pipe, use grep on it and pipe it again buffered. Here you used 4 different executables ... it has to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this small C program that I just made a minute ago.

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char needle[] = "mj";

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int fd, i, res, count;
  struct stat st;
  char * data;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Syntax: %s file\n", *argv);
    return 1;
  }

  fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file \"%s\": %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  res = fstat(fd, &st);
  if (res < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed at fstat: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  if (!S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File \"%s\" is not a regular file.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  data = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (!data) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap failed!: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < st.st_size; i++) {
    // look for string:
    if (i + sizeof needle - 1 < st.st_size
    && !memcmp(data + i, needle, sizeof needle - 1)) {
      count++;
      i += sizeof needle - 1;
    }
    while (data[i] != '\n' && i < st.st_size)
      i++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile it with: `gcc grepmj.c -o grepmj -O2`

Comment: It was a one liner question and took less time. I appreciate you effort but think simply.